# xdg-mime query default http://google.com hangs

Tags: linux, steam, xdg

running a normal query

`xdg-mime query default http://google.com`

hangs until I move/remove

`~/.local/share/applications/Steam`

output from running [fbrokendesktop](https://github.com/AndyCrowd/fbrokendesktop) to try to find errors:

```bsh
$ fbrokendesktop
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sh: -c: line 0: `which "/home/username/GOG &> /dev/null;if [ $? -ne 0 ];then echo "/home/username/GOG /home/username/Desktop/gog_com-Kerbal_Space_Program_1.desktop;fi '
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sh: -c: line 0: `which "/home/username/GOG &> /dev/null;if [ $? -ne 0 ];then echo "/home/username/GOG /home/username/Desktop/gog_com-Kerbal_Space_Program_2.desktop;fi '
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sh: -c: line 0: `which "/home/username/GOG &> /dev/null;if [ $? -ne 0 ];then echo "/home/username/GOG /home/username/Desktop/gog_com-Darkest_Dungeon_1.desktop;fi '
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sh: -c: line 0: `which "/home/username/GOG &> /dev/null;if [ $? -ne 0 ];then echo "/home/username/GOG /home/username/Desktop/gog_com-Hollow_Knight_1.desktop;fi '
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sh: -c: line 0: `which "/home/username/GOG &> /dev/null;if [ $? -ne 0 ];then echo "/home/username/GOG /home/username/Desktop/gog_com-Slay_the_Spire_1.desktop;fi '
```

but not which files they are in.

I believe this problem is causing many errors on my desktop including: drag and drop files from file explorers [all of them I have tried] hangs, and thunderbird hangs quickly after startup

Answer (score 0):

Back up all the installed games in my steam library (somewhere other than default since it defaults to somewhere inside `.local/share/applications/Steam`). Then delete `.local/share/applications/Steam`. Then use steam normally.

Seems that xdg-open works correctly now. `fbrokendesktop` still reports problems though